# What does "using VirtualFn1_t = void(__thiscall*)(void* thisptr);" means in c++?

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

I am trying to understand hooking while reading source code For virtual function method table hooking from wikipedia I came accross this line.

```
using VirtualFn1_t = void(__thiscall*)(void* thisptr);
```

I don't know what its mean . Is it casting void pointer to calling convention and recasting it into void pointer and using it as VirtualFn1_t alias. I also wanna understand what `void (__thiscall*)(void* thisptr)` and `(__thiscall*)(void* thisptr)` means .

Here is the full source from wikipedia.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"

using namespace std;

class VirtualClass
{
public:

    int number;

    virtual void VirtualFn1() //This is the virtual function that will be hooked.
    {
        cout << "VirtualFn1 called " << number++ << "\n\n";
    }
};




using VirtualFn1_t = void(__thiscall*)(void* thisptr); 
VirtualFn1_t orig_VirtualFn1;


void __fastcall hkVirtualFn1(void* thisptr, int edx) //This is our hook function which we will cause the program to call instead of the original VirtualFn1 function after hooking is done.
{
    cout << "Hook function called" << "\n";

    orig_VirtualFn1(thisptr); //Call the original function.
}




int main()
{
    VirtualClass* myClass = new VirtualClass(); //Create a pointer to a dynamically allocated instance of VirtualClass.

    void** vTablePtr = *reinterpret_cast<void***>(myClass); //Find the address that points to the base of VirtualClass' VMT (which then points to VirtualFn1) and store it in vTablePtr.

    DWORD oldProtection;
    VirtualProtect(vTablePtr, 4, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection); //Removes page protection at the start of the VMT so we can overwrite its first pointer.

    orig_VirtualFn1 = reinterpret_cast<VirtualFn1_t>(*vTablePtr); //Stores the pointer to VirtualFn1 from the VMT in a global variable so that it can be accessed again later after its entry in the VMT has been 
                                                                  //overwritten with our hook function.

    *vTablePtr = &hkVirtualFn1; //Overwrite the pointer to VirtualFn1 within the virtual table to a pointer to our hook function (hkVirtualFn1).

    VirtualProtect(vTablePtr, 4, oldProtection, 0); //Restore old page protection.

    myClass->VirtualFn1(); //Call the virtual function from our class instance. Because it is now hooked, this will actually call our hook function (hkVirtualFn1).
    myClass->VirtualFn1();
    myClass->VirtualFn1();

    delete myClass;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: documentation for [__thiscall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2019).  It does not appear that this question is regarding the C programming language, should not have the `c` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since C++11, `using` is the new way to create type aliases. It is similar (but more flexible) than a `typedef`.

The `using` statement in this question:

```
using VirtualFn1_t = void(__thiscall*)(void* thisptr);
```

is equivalent to this `typedef`:

```
typedef void (__thiscall *VirtualFn1_t)(void* thisptr);
```

Both statements are defining `VirtualFn1_t` as a new type that is a *pointer* to a function that:

- takes a `void*` as an input parameter
- uses the [`__thiscall`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2019) calling convention
- returns a `void`.

`orig_VirtualFn1` is declared as a variable of type `VirtualFn1_t` (thus `orig_VirtualFn1` is a pointer) , and is being pointed to the memory address of the original `VirtualClass::VirtualFn1()` method at runtime, before the vtable (virtual method table) of the `VirtualClass` class is modified to make the slot for `VirtualFn1()` point to the `hkVirtualFn1()` hook function instead.

Comment: Thanks now I have complete understanding of `VirtualFn1_t`.

Answer (score 2):

`VirtualFn1_t` is defined as an alias for the following type: a pointer to a function taking `void*` parameter, returning `void`, and using `__thiscall` calling convention.

Comment: Igor Tandetnik , Thanks for the answer.       So `void(__thiscall*)(void* thisptr);` should be same as `void (__thiscall *void)(void * ptr);` as they are about function pointer ??

Comment: No, it's not the same: `void (__thiscall *void)(void *)` doesn't compile. Try it.

Comment: I mean `void (__thiscall  *void)(void * ptr);` is a function pointer too.

Comment: No, `void (__thiscall *void)(void * ptr);` is meaningless and produces a compiler error. Try it.

Comment: Okk, It failed in compilation.. Thanks I understood the point...